# converting a text file into separate CSV files according to its specifications

Tags: python, pandas, csv, export-to-csv

I have a text file as follows.

```
Wednesday,01,September,2021
Wednesday,01,September,2021,00:15
cod,10,1=0,2=2
cod,18,1=27,2=18,3=20
Wednesday,01,September,2021
Wednesday,01,September,2021,00:30
cod,10,1=5,2=6
cod,18,1=20,2=19,3=15
```

I want to make separate CSV files as output in each of which the row is cod10 and cod18 respectively and the column labels are the keys (1=0 in cod,10 means the row name is cod10, the column name is 1 and the value is 0).
First CSV file:

```
id      1   2
cod10   0   2
cod10   5   6
```

Second CSV file:

```
id      1   2   3
cod18   27  18  20
cod18   20  19  15
```

I would be thankful for any idea.

Comment: is it guaranteed that "cod10" corresponds to "00:15" and "cod18" to "00:30"?

Comment: @enke, Thank you very much for your attention. It was a mistake and I corrected it in output CSV files.

Comment: What did you learn from the answers to [your last question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71086859/246801) that you can apply here? How have you modified those solutions to try and address this very similar problem?

Comment: @Zach Young, you're right somehow. But gathering the records that begin with the same cod# in one file is my new problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could open and read the text file and save only the rows that start with "cod". For those rows, you split on "=" and save the result in a nested dictionary:

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    lines = f.read().split('\n')
    out = {}
    for line in lines:
        first, id_num, *splits = line.split(',')
        if first == 'cod':
            for s in splits:
                k, v = s.split('=')
                out.setdefault(first + id_num, {}).setdefault(int(k), []).append(v)
```

Then this produces a dictionary that looks like:

```
{'cod10': {1: ['0', '5'], 2: ['2', '6']}, 
 'cod18': {1: ['27', '20'], 2: ['18', '19'], 3: ['20', '15']}}
```

Now since you tagged this as pandas, you could use pandas to create a DataFrame object for each key-value pair of `out` (produced above) and then save the values at each id as a csv as below. The main job here is to `explode` the columns (since each cell houses a list):

```
for k, v in out.items():
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({k:v}, orient='index').rename_axis(index=['id'])
    df = df.explode(df.columns.tolist()).reset_index()
    df.to_csv(f'file_{k}.csv')
    print(df, end='\n\n\n')
```

Output:

```
      id  1  2
0  cod10  0  2
1  cod10  5  6


      id   1   2   3
0  cod18  27  18  20
1  cod18  20  19  15
```